# How can I bulk rename table columns in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite

I created a whole bunch of SQLite database tables. Many columns in the tables have names with spaces, which I'm now realizing was not such a brilliant idea. Is there a way to write one command which will get rid of all spaces in all columns in all tables? I know I can do it one at a time (all potential duplicates seem to address this issue rather than my issue) but it's going to take me forever. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Write a program to generate and execute all the needed alter table statements.

Comment: How do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL to find all of the column names that contain spaces. I also included SQL to generate a new name.

```
SELECT t.name as tablename, c.name as badcol, replace(c.name, ' ','_') as newcolname 
FROM sqlite_master t
JOIN pragma_table_info(t.name) c
WHERE t.type = 'table' AND c.name like '% %';
```

From here you would have to generate alter statements looking like this:

```
ALTER table <tablename> RENAME COLUMN <badcol> to <newcolname>;
```

While I cant figure how to directly pass the list of parms to the Alter table command you can use the following SQL to generate the alter commands for you then just copy/paste the result and execute the list of them.

```
SELECT ('ALTER TABLE ' || t.name || ' RENAME COLUMN ' || '[' || c.name || ']' 
|| ' TO ' || '[' || REPLACE(c.name, ' ','_') || '];') 
FROM sqlite_master t 
JOIN pragma_table_info(t.name) c 
WHERE t.type = 'table' AND c.name like '% %';
```

In this SQL I replaced the spaces in col names with underscores but you can see where you could replace the REPLACE function with the column renaming solution you desire.

Comment: You can't pass entities(names) as parameters, so as you say you can just build the alter statements.